# How to intercept and tamper HTTP responses with Java?

Tags: java, xml, soap, jax-ws, byte-order-mark

I have a Java application performing different http requests which I don't control directly (SOAP requests via Jaxws generated client). I have some difficulties with BOM flags in front of the XML prolog which I want to avoid currently. I would like to intercept the HTTP response and tamper with it before I let javax.xml parse the correct SOAP envelope.

Now to my question: How can I elegantly intercept any HTTP response with Java without the need of Fiddler or any other proxy?
Can I implement something like a proxy class and register it in the HTTP connection factory?
Would it be possible to implement a "real" http proxy doing the cleaning work for me?

I'm using `org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.4.1` with Maven to create the stubs from WSDL.

*Important:* I only control the client, not the server. Therefore I can only make Java accept/parse the BOM flag in front of the response envelope *or* filter it out so that javax.xml can parse it normally.

Comment: I'd recommend that you use a filter or aspect.

Comment: Which JAX-WS implementation are you using? CXF? Axis?...

Comment: @duffymo: Thank you! Filter is unfortunately a very unhelpful keyword (servlet filter etc.). Could you tell me some sources or pointers what kind of filters they are?

Comment: HTTP filters are what you want.  It's most helpful.  SOAP services mean XML over HTTP, so servlet/HTTP filters are exactly the right thing.

Comment: You may also try to find if there are `bom` using hex editor.

Comment: @Rao: There are BOM flags and if I edit them out with Fiddler, the request succeeds

Comment: @duffymo: HTTP filters like in the servlet definition? If you have any pointers how to inject the filters to the HTTP connections, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Not in the connections. You have no control over those. It is applied to the service. I use spring; that makes it easy for me. How do you deploy your service? Which app server?

Comment: I think that's the gap... I don't own the service and don't control the service. I only control my client. Therefore I need to either make Java to accept the BOM flag in front of the envelope (response!) or filter it out manually (in the response!).

Comment: I figured another solution for my problem: I now use CXF in my app and this lib is handling the BOM correctly. Thanks @GuyBouallet !

Comment: If you still have a similar requirement in the future, you may use cxf interceptors. They should allow you to process the message in any phase of the input chain. They are well described here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

Comment: Thanks again! If you add that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Comment added as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use cxf interceptors. They should allow you to process the message in any phase of the input chain. They are well described [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html).